# ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to start up network using following command

```
./network_setup.sh up  channel
```

After running this command I am receiving this errro

```
ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest not found
```

How I can remove this error?please help me

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This error information reveals that currently there is NO existing 'latest' tag in most 'fabric-*' images on the public docker Hub. We have to specify which image version we want to pull, either in docker command or docker-compose file

You can find all available tags of 'fabric-orderer' [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-orderer/tags/)

For example:

1. In docker command

> # pull to local before using it
>   docker pull hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1
>   # rename it to 'latest'
>   docker tag hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0-rc1 hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest

2. **Recommended**: specify tag in docker compose file

Please try to find the docker-compose file used in network_setup.sh.

If you are using 1.0beta, it should be **docker-compose-cli.yaml**

In docker-compose-cli.yaml if you see:

> extends:
>        file:   base/docker-compose-base.yaml

then in **base/docker-compose-base.yaml** if you see this:

> ...
>   image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
>   ...

change it to be

> image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:**x86_64-1.0.0-rc1**

This fix is recommended also applied to fabric-peer, fabric-ca setting in **base/docker-compose-base.yaml** for alignment.

**EDIT** The problem no longer exists. Now the default latest tag will be provided by fabric team.

Comment: Side note: to figure out which tag to use, take a look at this section of the docs: <http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html#download-platform-specific-binaries> Download and look at the shell script and see how it is that they download the binaries.

Comment: works like a charm, i am getting same error with fabric-can now.

Comment: cant locate this file. tried using command locate docker-compose-base.yaml bit didnt found any thing

Comment: @DeepakBhavsar the fabric-sample code bases change a lot over years. And my answer might not be updated enought.  Free free to create a github issue for it and ping me github:davidkhala to continue the discussion.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:
replace the below line in yaml file:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
```

with line:

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.0.0
```

You can choose some other version as well based on availability in docker hub ( https://hub.docker.com/r/hyperledger/fabric-orderer/tags/ )

Comment: where can I find that yaml file

Answer (score 5):

You cannot just run ./network_setup.sh. Before you run ./netork_setup.sh, to generate or to docker pull images is necessary.

```
sudo rm -Rf $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger 
mkdir -pv $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger 
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger 
git clone http://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric 
git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric 
git branch --all 
git fetch
make clean
make dist-clean
make configtxgen
make docker
make peer-docker
make orderer-docker
make couchdb

cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-ca
git branch --all
git fetch 
make clean
make dist-clean
make docker
```

To generate images by yourself, please refer to: 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/e2e_cli/end-to-end.rst

To docker pull existing images, please refer to:
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/dchackfest/samples/e2e

Comment: 404 on your last link.

Answer (score 5):

Downloading platform-specific binaries worked for me

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0
```

source:

- http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/samples.html

Comment: curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.4.0 1.5.2

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation there's an easily missed script: 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/v1.1.0-alpha/samples.html

`curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.1.0-alpha`

The script downloads the Hyperledger Fabric docker images from Docker Hub into your local Docker environment and tag them as ‘latest’. It's very fast and does the job better than renaming all the files.

Also if you actually pull the Fabric repository from Github and do a `make docker` it will create the `:latest` images.

Answer (score 1):

By mistake, I had deleted all the hyper ledger fabric images from Docker so I was getting this error I solved by again calling cmd

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this error that means you need to specify a correct docker image tag

to solve the issue just relaunch the install script it will pull correct cocker images

```
curl -sSL https://bit .ly/2ysbOFE | bash -s -- 2.2.2 1.4.9
```

as indicated here
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/test_network.html

Comment: In current 2.4 docs , this is in [Install Fabric samples , Advanced download options](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.4/install.html#advanced-download-options) for latest release

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and what I did was to go to the console and list all the docker images I had in my computer with:

```
docker images --all
```

And I got a list like this:

```
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
dev-peer0.org1.example.com-fabcar-1.0   latest              2b951138a408        10 hours ago        173MB
<none>                                  <none>              0dc88d79f8bf        10 hours ago        173MB
<none>                                  <none>              94c8e5b3db58        10 hours ago        173MB
hyperledger/fabric-ca                   x86_64-1.1.0        72617b4fa9b4        6 weeks ago         299MB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                latest              b7bfddf508bc        6 weeks ago         1.46GB
hyperledger/fabric-tools                x86_64-1.1.0        b7bfddf508bc        6 weeks ago         1.46GB
```

So, given that the version I know I downloaded was 1.1.0, I went to the **docker-compose.yml** file and looked for all the lines that started with **image:** and added at the end the same tag that the images had. For example:

```
image:hyperledger/fabric-ca
```

was updated to

```
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:x86_64-1.0.0
```